# Obtener una parte de la cadena de texto con split en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una ventana de un formulario en c# en donde tengo un botón que va a buscar un archivo, para ello uso el siguiente código:

```
open.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|dat files (*.dat)|*.dat|Excel files (*.xls;*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && open.ToString() != " ")
{
    txt_RutaArchivo.Text = open.FileName; //o mostramos en el textline
    ruta = open.FileName; //se guarda en variable para ser usado después

    MessageBox.Show(ruta);
    extension = Path.GetExtension(ruta);

    if (extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx")
    {
        txt_NomHojaExcel.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Internamente tengo que rescatar el nombre del archivo, esto lo hago de esta forma:

En la variable **ruta**, guardo la dirección de dónde tengo el archivo, ej: **D:\Area de Trabajo SM\Rentas\archivo.txt**

y lo que necesito es que en una variable pueda guardar sólo la parte de *archivo.txt*

Y para esto creé una función a la que le envío la ruta y ahí la separe con el uso de split:

```
public static string ObtenerNombreArchivo(string valor)
{
    string str = "";  //acá es donde quiero guardar el archivo.txt
    string patron = "\\";

    string[] rutas = valor.Split(patron);


    foreach (string r in rutas)
    {
        str = r;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Acorde a lo que hice me debería guardar en **str** el valor de *archivo.txt*, pero así como lo tengo me sale marcado en rojo la palabra *patron* dentro del split y este dice que no se puede convertir de string a char.

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la función `split` necesita como separador un parámetro de tipo char, no un string. Cambiando la variable patron a un char se corrige el error:

```
char patron = '\\';
string[] rutas = valor.Split(patron);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener el nombre ya existe en .net la funcionalidad

```
string ruta = @"D:\Area de Trabajo SM\Rentas\archivo.txt";

string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(ruta);
```

Para usar la clase `Path` recuerda definir el

```
using System.IO;
```

[Path.GetFileName()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.5)

Comment: que fácil jajaja. Muchas Gracias